Does the gradient of the probability density tell me in which direction the system is most likely moving?
Suppose that a system is described by a probability density $\rho$ on the state space $S$. Of course we need to assume some additional structure on $S$ to define the gradient $\nabla\rho$. I am actually considering the simple case $S=\mathbb R$ such that $\nabla\rho$ is simply the derivative of $\rho$.
That being said, there seems to exist the following heuristic: If the system is prepared in the state $x\in S$, then the system is most likely moving in the direction of fastest increase of $\rho$, i.e. in the direction of $\nabla\rho(x)$ or $-\nabla\rho(x)$, depending on your convention. In particular, $\nabla\rho$ contains information about the most likely trajectories.

Is there some sort of intuitive argument for this behaviour?
Are there any examples where this method is applied? For example, what about the pathwise approach to metastability?
Is my question related to probability currents discussed in QM?


The statement is wrong. Consider harmonic oscillator in ground state. S being R

@Confuse-ray30 Do you mean the quantum harmonic oscillator? Can you please elaborate?

The ground state is a gaussian (centered around the minimum). The squared is thus also a gaussian. In particular, it does not evolve in time.

@Confuse-ray30 Thanks for the reminder! Okay, but how does this contradict the title? Based on the heuristic, I would expect that if I start the system away from the origin, it initially moves towards the origin. And that is precisely what happens, isn't it?

That's not what you said. You claim: " If the system is prepared in the state x∈S, then ∇ρ(x) is the direction in which the system is most likely moving". I.e. see my answer soon TM

Where does this idea come from? Brownian motion in 1D can be explained by random motion of particles where any single particle motion does not depend on $\rho$ or its gradient at all. Their motion is random, with all directions equally likely, and this by itself implies $\rho$ becomes smoother in time.

@JánLalinský I think that this idea comes from one-dimensional nearest-neighbour random walks, since the principle holds true in that context (as Giorgio pointed out). I am very happy with the answer.

@Filippo Giorgio's example is detailed balance. Random walks do not always obey detailed balance. Detailed balance requires stationary $\rho$.

"Random walks do not always obey detailed balance." - But (irreducible) birth-death processes - that's what I meant by one-dimensional nearest-neighbour random walks - do, don't they?

The hypothesis is false. In some sense, in the case of a stationary probability density, things may go the other way around.
Indeed, let's assume that we have a probability density $\rho(x)$ and that the values of $\rho$ at two neighbor points $x_1$ and $x_2$ are such that.
$$
\rho(x_1)> \rho(x_2).
$$
This condition implies that, on average, more representative points are in a region $dx$ around $x_1$ than around $x_2$. We can define a probability of transition from $x_1$ to $x_2$ as $\pi(x_1,x_2)$, and, symmetrically, from $x_2$ to $x_1$ as $\pi(x_2,x_1)$. Such transition probability contains the information about where a system is most likely moving. Now, a sufficient condition for a stationary $\rho$ is the so-called detailed balance, i.e., on average, the same number of systems go from $x_1$ to $x_2$ as from $x_2$ to $x_1$. But this implies
$$
\rho(x_1)\pi(x_1,x_2) = \rho(x_2)\pi(x_2,x_1),
$$
from where do we obtain
$$
\frac{\pi(x_1,x_2)}{\pi(x_2,x_1)} = \frac{\rho(x_2)}{\rho(x_1)}
$$
This is saying the opposite of the proposed hypothesis: the transition probability from a low to a higher probability region is higher than from high to low.
Notice that this is a counterexample. The detailed balance is not a necessary hypothesis.
Finally, the current probability in Quantum Mechanics cannot be expressed in terms of the gradient of the probability density.

Thank you for your answer. I think that there was a misunderstanding: My convention is that the gradient points in the direction of fastest increase, so you actually proved my point. Sorry for the confusion.

@Filippo, maybe you missed the final notice. The detailed balance is just a sufficient t hypothesis. It can be used as a counter-example but does not prove that the transition probability from low to high probability density must always be higher than the reversed one.

I read your final notice, but I asked for examples where my principle holds true and you gave me a nice example: One-dimensional nearest-neighbour random walks. In fact, the setup that I am considering is very similar, so you helped me more than you can possibly imagine. Thank you!

Now that I am home, here is the general answer.
Your claim is, as far as I understood: Probability densities relax to a constant. Like Fick's law.
This means $\partial_t \rho \propto -\nabla \rho$.
My claim is: Let $S$ be unbounded. Then this is never true.
Proof: Suppose this is true. Then the steady state is given by $\nabla\rho=0$.
This implies $\rho=|\psi(x)|^2=const$.
Since $S$ is unbounded, the state is thus not in $L^2$, i.e. not normalizable. Thus it is unphysical.

Thank you very much for taking the time to write a full answer. I need some time to digest it.

@Filippo I seem to have misunderstood/misinterpreted your question just as Giorgio did, as my sign is wrong. But nonetheless, even with a positive sign in front of the gradient, it leads to unphysical states. (Or there simply may never be a stable state.)
